# Inspect Element Console Loops message "Console Cleared"

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, debugging, console

I am trying to inspect element this site https://www.supremenewyork.com/, upon inspecting element in any browser I experience a paused in debugger error I have removed this by disabling break points however the console flashes with the message "console cleared" and I cannot type anything into the console.

Comment: so they are clearing the console.....

Answer (score 0):

So they must be calling console.clear() on a loop of some sort.

So you can click "preserve log" which prevents clearing of the console or you can try to overwrite console.clear so it does something else

```
 console.clear = function () {}
```

, but they can get around that.....

Basically they do not want you to be using the console. :)